# Maven Internal error: org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.OsgiManifestParserException: Exception parsing OSGi MANIFEST

Tags: java, maven, dsl, xtext, tycho

I am configuring maven for few dsl (xtext) types of projects.
I configured all I need for a dsl1 (xtext) plugins, it worked successfully (generate java sources, build, run tests, export, generate P2).

Then, I moved same pom.xml configurations for my next dsl2 plugins, that are pretty the same and got an issue:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.xtext:xtext-maven-plugin:2.16.0.M1:generate (default) on project com.dsl.dsl2: Execution default of goal org.eclipse.xtext:xtext-maven-plugin:2.16.0.M1:generate failed: Plugin org.eclipse.xtext:xtext-maven-plugin:2.16.0.M1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.dsl.dsl2:com.dsl.dsl2:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

The plugin that run is `com.dsl.dsl2` and it tells that it can not find itself.
Indeed for some reason maven fails to copy it into corresponding `.m2/repository` location. 
I tried different solutions to solve it, and one of them was to remove the whole `~/.m2/repository` and to regenerate it. 
But now, instead of solving my problem, I am facing different other problems.

For all my repos that worked before to run `mvn clean verify`, now all complains with same error:

```
[INFO] Resolving class path of MavenProject: com.dsl.dsl2:com.dsl.dsl2:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT @ /<my_path>/<my_repo>/com.dsl.dsl2/pom.xml
[ERROR] Internal error: org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.OsgiManifestParserException: Exception parsing OSGi MANIFEST ~/.m2/repository/p2/osgi/bundle/org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator/2.15.0.v20180916-0722/org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator-2.15.0.v20180916-0722.jar: zip file is empty -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.OsgiManifestParserException: Exception parsing OSGi MANIFEST ~/.m2/repository/p2/osgi/bundle/org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator/2.15.0.v20180916-0722/org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator-2.15.0.v20180916-0722.jar: zip file is empty
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:120)
    ...
Caused by: org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.OsgiManifestParserException: Exception parsing OSGi MANIFEST ~/.m2/repository/p2/osgi/bundle/org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator/2.15.0.v20180916-0722/org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator-2.15.0.v20180916-0722.jar: zip file is empty
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.DefaultBundleReader.doLoadManifest (DefaultBundleReader.java:68)
    ...
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open (Native Method)
    ...
```

I am most interested in solving this last issue first. The jar file seems to be correct:

```
% ls -lsa ~/.m2/repository/p2/osgi/bundle/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86/3.105.3.v20170228-0512/
2568 <user> 2616403  org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86-3.105.3.v20170228-0512.jar
   4 <user> 219      org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86-3.105.3.v20170228-0512-p2artifacts.xml
```

And I don't know why it is using xtext 2.15.0 as
I specified in pom.xml properties

```
<xtend.version>2.16.0.M1</xtend.version>
<xtext.version>2.16.0.M1</xtext.version>
```

My maven:

```
% mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.5.4 (1edded0938998edf8bf061f1ceb3cfdeccf443fe; 2018-06-17T21:33:14+03:00)
Maven home: ~/maven/apache-maven-3.5.4
Java version: 1.8.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: 
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ISO-8859-1
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

And I am using proxy.

### Update

That is the content of unzipped jar it complains about.

```
% ls  /org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86-3.105.3.v20170228-0512
about_files  fragment.properties     libswt-cairo-gtk-4629.so  libswt-gtk-4629.so          libswt-pi-gtk-4629.so         libswt-xulrunner-fix10.so     META-INF  swt.xpt
about.html   libswt-atk-gtk-4629.so  libswt-glx-gtk-4629.so    libswt-mozilla-gtk-4629.so  libswt-webkit-gtk-4629.so     libswt-xulrunner-fix31.so     org       version.txt
chrome.manifest  libswt-awt-gtk-4629.so  libswt-gnome-gtk-4629.so  libswt-pi3-gtk-4629.so      libswt-xpcominit-gtk-4629.so  libswt-xulrunner-gtk-4629.so  swt.js
```

I am using simple target platform configuration:

```
    <repository>
        <id>xtext</id>
        <url>http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/composite/releases/</url>
        <layout>p2</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>eclipse</id>
        <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201705151400/</url>
        <layout>p2</layout>
    </repository>
```

### Update

I have solved my problem, but I can't say that it's a solution for the problems I had.

- The last error I had is about Time Out due to Proxy limitations, I
  believe. It has been solved in next day by itself.
- The 1st outlined error I solved by recreating my pom configurations based on  https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/350_continuous_integration.html

Basically,  I am not using any more `<artifactId>xtext-maven-plugin</artifactId>` that was failing, and it is recommended to use it in a non Eclipse plugin in case you need. I don't need it.

Comment: what is configured in your target platform? can you unzip the jars? org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator-2.15.0.v20180916-0722.jar?
what happens if you delete your maven repo or use a user one `-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2`

Comment: If I delete my maven repo, It tries to recreate it, but I have to run mvn few times, as it stops downloading at some point. I think am getting 'timed out'. I am using simple target platform configuration <repository>
   <id>xtext</id>
   <url>http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/composite/releases/</url>
   <layout>p2</layout>
  </repository>
  <repository>
   <id>eclipse</id>
   <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201705151400/</url>
   <layout>p2</layout>
  </repository>

Comment: Sometimes eclipse download servers behave bad. If problem continues open a bug at eclipse.org bugzilla

Comment: ok, thank you Christian

Comment: But, Chistian, if my first problem is related to time out, and will be solved at the end, Do you know what could be the reason for my first reported problem?

Comment: did you have a look at the file on disk. is it ok?

Comment: yes, the jar is missing, for some reason, it fails to copy it into .m2 repo. Seems to be related to dependencies.

Comment: => how do you build? are versions correct?

Comment: I do have same version in both plugin.xml and pom.xml. I run mvn clean verify from command line. I get rid of time out issue, and now I am trying to solve this problem ( Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.xtext:xtext-maven-plugin ... Could not find artifact com.dsl.dsl2:com.dsl.dsl2:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT) that I have now for 2 repos, for one of which worked before. Strange.

Comment: did you do a install to the local maven repo before (clean install vs clean verify)

Comment: yes, I did it again, still same problem. Only root/relang project is copied into local maven repo.

Comment: again: with no idea how the layout of your projects is and how you build the first project

Comment: Thank you Christian, I will try to solve it. When I check efective pom I have different versions for some plugins, could this be a problem, the plugin name and version has been inherited, I have not defined them. E.g. maven-install-plugin top plugin has 2.3.1, and child 2.4; maven-deploy-plugin  top plugin has 2.5 version, and child 2.7

Comment: no that does not matter. the question is how structure of projects is

Comment: That's my pom files and project structure, a root project and a child project inside it: http://lidia.gq/com.dsl.dsl2.root/pom.xml and http://lidia.gq/com.dsl.dsl2.root/com.dsl.dsl2/pom.xml , If it helps. thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183496/discussion-between-christian-dietrich-and-lidia).